# Compare strings using awk command

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am at initial stage of learning shell scripting. So please explain me the steps for better understanding.

Consider I have two files

Content of the two files are as below:

File1.txt

```
ABC=10
DEF=20
XYZ=30
```

File2.txt

```
DEF=15
XYZ=20
```

I want to write a simple shell script to check both the files and add the values and print the final output as below. like

```
ABC=10
DEF=35
XYZ=50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {a[$1]+=$2} 
     END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file1 file2
ABC=10
XYZ=50
DEF=35
```

**Breakup:**

```
NR == FNR {                  # While processing the first file
  a[$1] = $2                 # store the second field by the first in an array
  next                       # move to next record
}
{                            # while processing the second file
  a[$1]+=$2                  # add already stored value by 2nd field in 2nd file                                 
}
END{..}                      # iterate the array and print the values
```

---

If you want to keep original ordering intact then use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} FNR==NR{if (!($1 in a)) b[++n]=$1; a[$1]=$2;next} {a[$1]+=$2}
     END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print b[i], a[b[i]]}' file1 file2
ABC=10
DEF=35
XYZ=50
```

Comment: Thanks for responding for my query, can you please explain me in details as i am very new to scripting/programming..